# How do I convert a waveform from arduino into a csv file that a user can download?

Tags: export-to-csv, arduino-uno

I am using the following code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int val = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(val);

}
```

To plot the waveform onto the serial monitor. From there, I want to somehow convert the signal I receieve into a csv file for further analysis. What steps should I take? Thanks